# Change clementine's colour theme

Tags: themes, qt, colors, clementine

Clementine's left bar, volume control and the current song's highlighting are all orange, how can I change that?

Clementine has appearance settings in the preferences window, setting the colour theme to custom looks like you dropped some paint on the player. The things I want to change stay the same but the backgrounds take the colour.

Apparently clementine's theme can be changed using qtconfig but it doesn't have colour settings and it *is* set to orange. Where to go next?
[image: clementine]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question? Cause I don't see anything orange in my clementine .

Comment: @Ravexina here you go. You can call it brown if you want to..

Comment: I managed to change Clementine's default colors with qt5ct:
https://www.pcsuggest.com/qt5ct-change-qt5-application-style/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible to do, I search a little bit and even poked around Clementine's `db` file but no luck.

What I found is that if you set `GTK+` as default GUI theme in `qtconfig`, Clementine will match it selfs with GTK's widgets style.

I use `lxappearance` to change my widgets theme. When it's been set on `crux` I get the left one and after changing it to `Greybird` I get the right one.

[image] [image]

So the only way that I found is changing the GTK's widgets style.